# Index a ruby array to omit an element or range of elements?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a ruby array of, say, 10 elements, and I'd like to return all but the 5th element.

```
a = *(1..10)
```

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
a[0..3 + 5..9]
```

Or even better something like (borrowing from the R syntax),

```
a[-4]
```

to do this, but that doesn't work.  (Nor does anything more clever I've tried like getting an array of the element indices).  What's the best way to do this in ruby?

Comment: what's the problem with the trivial `a[0..3] + a[5..9]`?

Comment: It seems very rare that you would need such functionality. Can you talk more about what you're doing? e.g. how do you know you want to omit index 4? If you are tracking offsets, there is probably a better data structure. If you're finding it dynamically before you build this new array, then there's almost certainly better ways to accomplish this process using the Enumerable methods (e.g. `(1..10).reject { |element| element == 5 }`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No black magic required:

```
a[0..3] + a[5..9]
```

Comment: Not really the best solution here IMO because this doesn't work when your index to omit is the first or last index in the array.

Comment: @Calvin: this? `a[0...n] + a[n+1...a.length]`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `values_at`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-values_at

so you may use it as

```
a.values_at(0..3, 5..9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in the documentation under `Array#delete_at`

For example, `myarray.delete_at(5)` results in the array lacking what was element 5 (counting from 0, of course).

Example:

```
class Array
  def without(n)
    self.delete_at(n)
    return self
  end
end
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
p arr.without(1) #=> [1, 3, 4]
```

However, as a commenter points out, this alters the original array, which may not be what the O.P. wants! If that's an issue, write it like this:

```
class Array
  def without(n)
    arr2 = Array.new(self)
    arr2.delete_at(n)
    return arr2
  end
end
```

That returns the desired array (an array lacking the nth element of the original) while leaving the original array untouched.

Comment: There are two problems with that: 1. it changes the original array and, 2. it doesn't return the array without removed element but it returns the removed element.

Comment: revised to incorporate that part of the spec :)

Comment: Looks nice but try 

    `p arr.without(1) #=> [1, 3, 4];
    p arr  #=> [1, 3, 4] unfortunately`

because delete_at changes the original array.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I thought that was what he wanted done. Now I see what you're getting at. Modified answer further to point out this flaw.

Comment: Updated solution looks good here and should be the accepted answer - one thing to note is that this is built into ActiveSupport for rails 5+ users :)